# How to delete a feature in Openlayers 3.8.2 with `del` Key

Tags: javascript, openlayers, events

I'm using [OpenLayers-3.8.2](http://openlayers.org/) for developing a GIS application. Users draw some features and can modify all existing features on the map. They can delete features. I can delete feature as follow:

1. user click some features
2. User click on a button and then: `layer.getSource().removeFeature(feature)`

Now I want the user to be able to remove features with `del` key.

What do I implement it?

Comment: No feedback...?

Answer (score 3):

This way:

```
var deleteFeature = function(evt){
    if(evt.keyCode == 46){ //delete key pressed
        //delete feature

    }
};
document.addEventListener('keydown', deleteFeature, false);
```