# Deleting selected feature in OpenLayers?

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I would like to delete my feature in OpenLayers by the "del" button.
I found some solutionss here:

[How to delete a feature in Openlayers 3.8.2 with `del` Key](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/157590/how-to-delete-a-feature-in-openlayers-3-8-2-with-del-key)

and combined it with the hint here:

```
    var deleteFeature = function(evt){
    if(evt.keyCode == 46){
    vectorLayer.getSource().clear();
    if (selectInteraction) {
    selectInteraction.getFeatures().clear();
    }
   }
   };
   document.addEventListener('keydown', deleteFeature, false);
```

but I just want to delete only the selected feature by the "del" button. Instead of it all are gone.

I tried to put instead:

```
 var deleteFeature = function(evt){
  if(evt.keyCode == 46){
  vectorLayer.getSource().removeFeature(SelectedFeature);
  }
  };
 document.addEventListener('keydown', deleteFeature, false);
```

but it looks like the `removeFeature(SelectedFeature)`;  doesn't work here

I tried also this solution:

https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/4214

but it didn't work either.

My full JS fiddle is here:

https://jsfiddle.net/z08kfcg7/

which includes pure .js only

How can I delete only one feature selected instead of all of them?

**UPDATE:**

I tried also:

```
 var selectInteraction = new ol.interaction.Select({
  condition: ol.events.condition.click,
  wrapX: false
  })

var deleteFeature = function(evt){
 if(evt.keyCode == 46){
  selectInteraction.getFeatures().clear();
 }
};
document.addEventListener('keydown', deleteFeature, false);
```

[image]

Nothing happens, just the feature previously selected is unselected now.

UPDATE:

```
function removeSelectedFeature() {
 var features = selectInteraction.getFeatures();
   if (features != null && features.length > 0) {
       for (x in features) {
         var properties = features[x].getProperties();
         console.log(properties);
         var id = properties.id;
         if (id == selectedFeatureID) {
          selectInteraction.removeFeature(features[x]);
            break;
         }
       }
     }
   }



 var deleteFeature = function(evt){
  if(evt.keyCode == 46){
    removeSelectedFeature();
   };
 
  };
   document.addEventListener('keydown', deleteFeature, false);
```

this one doesn't work either.

[Remove selected feature Openlayers 3](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/126909/remove-selected-feature-openlayers-3)

**UPDATE III**

```
   var deleteFeature = function(evt){
   if(evt.keyCode == 46){
  
  
  vectorLayer.getSource().removeFeature(selectInteraction.getFeatures());
 };

  };
   document.addEventListener('keydown', deleteFeature, false);
```

This piece of code throws an error:

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'forEach')
at e.removeFeatureInternal (Vector.js:906)
at e.removeFeature (Vector.js:896)
at HTMLDocument.deleteFeature (qgis2web.js:913)**

Comment: What exactly is "selected feature"? How do you identify it? Please edit your question with additional info.

Comment: If, for instance, I have 4 features in different geometry. I select one of them, it becomes highlighted, and then I can hit the "del" button and delete it.

Comment: How do you highlight the feature? At the time of highlight you could set some global var `selectedFeature` to that feature and then use `vectorLayer.getSource().removeFeature(selectedFeature); ` to delete it at the time of key press.

Comment: how this global var could look like then?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the relevant part of the code where you highlight the feature.

Comment: I am clicking it (selecting) not highlighting. Possibly I have misspelled. Sorry.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the relevant part of the code where you select the feature by clicking.

Comment: The question has been edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your last try (update III) you were almost there. Select interaction `.getFeatures()` method returns a collection of elements (see https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_interaction_Select-Select.html#getFeatures), so you have to either loop through it's members or refer to the only element. Reference is done with the `.item` method.

So your code could then look something like this:

```
var deleteFeature = function(evt){
  if(evt.keyCode == 46) {
    var selectCollection = selectInteraction.getFeatures();
    if (selectCollection.getLength() > 0) {
      vectorLayer.getSource().removeFeature(selectCollection.item(0));
    }
  };
};
document.addEventListener('keydown', deleteFeature, false);
```

Comment: Yeah! That was EXACTLY I was looking for. Many thanks. It looks like I haven't defined the additional variable. Lesson learned.